# How to run custom Docker file?

Tags: docker

So here is a very cool Docker [file](https://github.com/rocker-org/r-devel-san-clang/blob/master/Dockerfile).

To run it, I do:

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/FastRCS_0.0.7.tar.gz 
tar -xvzf FastRCS_0.0.7.tar.gz 
docker run --rm -ti -v $(pwd):/mnt rocker/r-devel-ubsan-clang check.r --setwd /mnt -a --install-deps FastRCS_0.0.7.tar.gz
```

But now suppose I want to save this DockerFile and run the saved version from the current directory (i.e. not just the one on github).
 How can I do this?

The idea is that I need to customize this DockerFile a bit and run the customized version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want to download the raw file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rocker-org/r-devel-san-clang/master/Dockerfile
and save it into a file named `Dockerfile`
Then you could edit the file to make your changes, and then just build your image with `docker build .` when you are in the Dockerfile directory

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic Docker usage question--look into [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/commit/).

You may want to study one of the many fine Docker tutorials out there.

Comment: You mean there is no way to simply download one of those dockerfile and run that downloaded version? I'm trying to reduce overhead

Comment: You can, you then need to look into [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/build/) for building an image from a `Dockerfile`.

Comment: And you can store a modified container you already run -- that was my answer.  So again: please peruse some Docker tutorials first.